# "Setup operation failed" when installing Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: c#, installation, visual-studio-2017

When installing Visual studio, i get an error saying "Setup operation failed"

I get an option to view a log so I've placed in a pastebin

pastebin.com/bj8e5yyb

None of the troubleshooting tips or anything else on the internet work.

PS. Im trying to install the universal windows package and the .net desktop development.

*EDIT*
Here is the revelant parts of the error log:

```
   Log
        C:\Users\Jmilicev\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170420190928_005_Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi.log
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi,version=15.0.26315.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1"  VS7.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
        Return code: 110
        Return code details: The system cannot open the device or file specified.
```

I would appreciate any ideas, Ive been trying to fix this for hours with no luck.

Comment: Please include logs, code, etc in the question itself; not as links. and please try to only include the *relevant* sections (you can still link to the full text if you want)

Comment: added relevant parts of the log